# Jquery não retorna segunda imagem na lista

Tags: jquery, html, css

Aparentemente, o código está correto, é o seguinte:

```
{
if( $(".ativo").next().size() ) 
{ 
    $(".ativo").fadeOut().removeClass("ativo").next().fadeIn().addClass("ativo")
}
else 
{ 
    $(".ativo").fadeOut().removeClass("ativo");
    $("#slide img").eq(0).fadeIn().addClass("ativo")
 }
```

E o html atual:

```
<div id="slide">

            <a href="CURSOS.html"><img id="slideIMG1" src="IMAGENS/mao (370px) - Final.jpg" width="1155" height="370" alt=""/></a>
            <a href="#"><img id="slideIMG2" src="IMAGENS/picjumbo (370px).jpg" width="1155" height="370" alt=""/></a>

         </div>
```

Comment: Cadê o `.ativo` no seu html? E o seletor da imagem está com o índice fixo `$("#slide img").eq(0)`. Vai sempre pegar a primeira imagem.

Comment: Não entendi, onde no código acima que está "retornando" alguma coisa? A propósito, na sua última linha você usa um `eq(0)`, então esse seletor é filtrado para se aplicar somente ao primeiro resultado previamente selecionado (i.e. se `"#slide img"` selecionou duas imagens, o `eq(0)` vai fazer com que só a primeira continue como parte do conjunto).

Comment: conforme o @DontVoteMeDown falou, realmente o eq(0) vai ativar somente a primeira imagem, mas afinal o que você quer fazer com um slide e duas imagens ?

Comment: Não entendi. Pois se houver algo após a primeira, é para ele exibir esse algo e adicionar a classe "ativo" a esse algo.

Comment: `ativo` é uma classe aplicada à imagem em si ou ao link (`a`)? Se for ao `img`, acho que identifiquei seu problema... (nenhuma imagem aí tem `next`, elas são filhas únicas do seu `a`)

Comment: No caso acredito que ele aplica a classe ativo a imagem mesmo, de acordo com o seletor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema é que a imagem não tem irmãos, ela é filha única do link (`a`), de modo que o `next` não retornará nada. Para selecionar a próxima imagem, é necessário subir ao pai, pegar o próximo link e então descer de novo à imagem:

```js
function mudar() { 
            
    if( $(".ativo").parent().next().size() ) 
    { 
        $(".ativo").fadeOut().removeClass("ativo")
            .parent().next().children("img")
            .fadeIn().addClass("ativo")
    }
    else 
    { 
        $(".ativo").fadeOut().removeClass("ativo");
        $("#slide img").eq(0).fadeIn().addClass("ativo")
    }
}
mudar();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="mudar()">Teste</button>
<div id="slide">

    <a href="CURSOS.html"><img id="slideIMG1" src="http://sempreupdate.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google-small.png" alt="A"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="slideIMG2" src="https://s1.yimg.com/rz/d/yahoo_en-US_f_p_bestfit_2x.png" alt="B" class="ativo"/></a>

</div>
```

Alternativamente, você pode aplicar a classe ao `a` em vez do `img`, simplificando seu código (se for possível fazer isso sem "quebrar" demais seu CSS, é claro).

Comment: Funcionou. É isso mesmo. Muito obrigado.